# Is $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] safe to rely on?

Tags: php

My site relies heavily on `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`. Can I trust the data retrieved? There is a possibility of finding an empty string?

Comment: `SERVER_ADDR` should always be available if you're loading the page via a web server. What made you think it wouldn't be? `REMOTE_ADDR` and other settings for the client are unreliable, but your local `SERVER_ADDR` should always be valid.

Comment: A server might have several ip addresses. If consistency here is important to your application, you'd better examine how your web server behaves.

Comment: @spudley: How is remote_addr unreliable? It's extracted from the socket level setup and isn't subject to user manipulation, other than proxy/nat firewall stuff

Comment: @Mark B: if the user comes via a proxy, you may not get to see their real IP address.

Comment: @Spudley On my local web server, $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is empty.  Apparently the web server decides whether or not to include it.  Running Ubuntu.

Comment: If you are using docker, are behind a nginx proxy, or even cloudflare this can get messed up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the php reference I quoted some

It seems that it depends on the server hosting PHP (especially apache , IIS ...)

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> On Windows IIS 7 you must use
>   $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'] rather than
>   $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] to get the
>   server's IP address.

And another.

> Windows running IIS v6 does not
>   include $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
>
> If you need to get the IP addresse,
>   use this instead:

```
<?php $ipAddress =
 gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
?>
```

Comment: Warning: `gethostbyname` relies on a DNS lookup - this could present a significant performance penalty depending on your usage.

Answer (score 4):

From [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444769/marc-bouvier), this might work in a cross-platform situation:

```
array_key_exists('SERVER_ADDR',$_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] : $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'];
```

Comment: This yielded in `Undefined index: LOCAL_ADDR` on Debian Jessie while running PHPUnit

Answer (score 2):

I use the following function in a varying server environment (Windows and Linux):

```
function getServerAddress() {
if(array_key_exists('SERVER_ADDR', $_SERVER))
    return $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
elseif(array_key_exists('LOCAL_ADDR', $_SERVER))
    return $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'];
elseif(array_key_exists('SERVER_NAME', $_SERVER))
    return gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
else {
    // Running CLI
    if(stristr(PHP_OS, 'WIN')) {
        return gethostbyname(php_uname("n"));
    } else {
        $ifconfig = shell_exec('/sbin/ifconfig eth0');
        preg_match('/addr:([\d\.]+)/', $ifconfig, $match);
        return $match[1];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From an operations standpoint, relying on the interface name or hostname is a really really bad idea. Depending on the network driver or network configuration, the interface name can change at any time and so can the hostname. It is not something you as a developer can control, and therefore shouldn't be relied on. If you do, your application is going to break for a seemingly unrelated reason and you will be left with some painful debugging to do.

Short version: if the webserver doesn't tell you the IP address the request arrived on, you can't guess it. Period.