# PHP - Will the $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] variable always be unique and never change?

Tags: php

I have three quick questions regarding the PHP `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` variable. Will the variable be unique(only one on the whole internet)? Will the variable never change? If either of these questions is no, is there a way to identify the server uniquely on the internet via PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $\_SERVER\['SERVER\_ADDR'\] safe to rely on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705082/is-serverserver-addr-safe-to-rely-on)

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705082/is-serverserver-addr-safe-to-rely-on Since this is from the client-side, it is possible that the IP Address changes over time.

Comment: @Maximus2012 So could I use gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) to reliably get the IP address of the server?

Comment: Correction to my comment: Assuming that you control the server completely, `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` will give you IP of the server that the PHP script is running on. It should be reliable but the IP can still change based on how your server is configured. The same goes for `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` It can be changed if the Server Admin decides to do that. However, `SERVER_` variables in `$_SERVER` array should in general be more reliable than corresponding `REMOTE_` variables.

Comment: Do take a look at that other question that was linked in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but in comments you've asked:

> So could I use gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) to reliably get the IP address of the server?

The answer is generally: *no*. While the hostname of the server will not change, the IP can change during lifetime of a web application. Reasons for an IP change might be a relocation of servers from one hoster to another one.

Or even round robin based DNS load balancing where multiple IP addresses are assigned to the same hostname. Especially when the latter is used, `gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])` will continuously deliver a different IP address per DNS request.

Another reason would be web servers behind a load balancer. Then the IP address of the load balancer is assigned to the hostname, the web servers itself (where PHP is running) have internal addresses in that case.

Comment: So could I use the hostname of the server as a unique identifier?

Comment: It depends on your application, as long as you are using a single web server: yes. If the servers are behind a load balancer, or you use even DNS based load balancing: no.